# How to convert this c# linq-to-xml method into javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, linq-to-xml

I am converting legacy .NET server code into node.js server. Generally it's going OK but I am stuck with the code shown below.
I have found a library for a [JS LINQ equivalent](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq/blob/master/linq.d.ts) (which may be OTT for my requirements), and a library for [dealing with XML data](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js), but finding equivalents for  `Descendants` , `Attribute` etc is what's stopping me from progressing this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
        public static Track ParseGPX()
        {

            List<Position> Px = new List<Position>();
            IEnumerable<Track> tracks =
                    from trackElement in root.Descendants(ns1 + "trkseg")
                    select new Track
                    {
                        TrackPoints =
                            (from trackPointElement in trackElement.Descendants(ns1 + "trkpt")
                             select new TrackPoint
                             {
                                 pos = new Position
                                 {
                                     LatitudeDegrees = XmlConvert.ToDouble(trackPointElement.Attribute("lat").Value),
                                     LongitudeDegrees = XmlConvert.ToDouble(trackPointElement.Attribute("lon").Value),

                                 },
                                 AltitudeMeters = trackPointElement.Element(ns1 + "ele") != null
                                                 ? Convert.ToDouble(trackPointElement.Element(ns1 + "ele").Value) : 0.0,
                             }).ToList()
                    };

            return tracks.SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Microsoft has good documentation online for [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview).